# How I do a join for a specific result in 4 tables and there's one no related?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am new at mysql and I don't know how to get a specific result that i'm doing in database with 4 table but there's one no related and I dont know how to do.

```
create table PEP_PEOPLE(
  PEP_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PEP_NAME VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL
  );

create table COS_COSTUMER(
  COS_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  PEP_ID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(PEP_ID) REFERENCES PEP_PEOPLE(PEP_ID));

create table SEL_SELLERS(
  SEL_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  PEP_ID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(PEP_ID) REFERENCES PEP_PEOPLE(PEP_ID));

create table ORD_ORDERS(
  ORD_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ORD_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
  SEL_ID INT NOT NULL,
  COS_ID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(SEL_ID) REFERENCES SEL_SELLERS(SEL_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY(COS_ID) REFERENCES COS_COSTUMERS(COS_ID));
```

How do I get the costumers name, sellers name, the order date using the order ID as a reference?
I tried this:

```
SELECT ORD_ORDERS.ORD_ID, ORD_ORDERS.ORD_DATE
FROM ORD_ORDERS 
INNER JOIN SEL_SELLERS ON ORD_ORDERS.ORD_ID = SEL_SELLERS.PEP_ID
INNER JOIN COS_COSTUMER ON ORD_ORDERS.ORD_ID = COS_COSTUMERS.PEP_ID WHERE PED_CODIGO <=6;
```

Comment: Please don't tag SQL Server for a MySQL question.

Comment: I think this naming policy would fry my brain

Answer (score 1):

Follow the foreign key references.  This requires more joins to get to the people and the names:

```
SELECT O.ORD_ID, O.ORD_DATE, PS.NAME as Seller, PC.NAME as Customer
FROM ORD_ORDERS O JOIn
     SEL_SELLERS S
     ON O.SEL_ID = S.SEL_ID JOIN
     COS_COSTUMER C
     ON O.COS_ID = C.COS_ID JOIN
     PEP_PEOPLE PS
     ON S.PEP_ID = PS.PEPID JOIN
     PEP_PEOPLE PC
     ON C.PEP_ID = PC.PEPID
WHERE PED_CODIGO <= 6;
```